# too many values to unpack (expected 2) Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

```
datasets = {
    x:LungDataset(
        splits[x],
        origins_folder,
        masks_folder,
        train_transform if x == 'train' else val_test_transform
        
    ) for x in ["train", "test", "val"]
}
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datasets[x], batch_size=batch_size) for x in ["train", "test", "val"]}
```

```
idx = 0
phase = "train"

origin, mask = datasets[phase][idx]
```

```
class LungDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, origin_mask_list, origins_folder, masks_folder, transforms=None):
        self.origin_mask_list = origin_mask_list
        self.origins_folder = origins_folder
        self.masks_folder = masks_folder
        self.transforms = transforms

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        origin_name, mask_name = self.origin_mask_list[idx]
        origin = Image.open(self.origins_folder / (origin_name + ".png")).convert("P")
        mask = Image.open(self.masks_folder / (mask_name + ".png"))
        if self.transforms is not None:
            origin, mask = self.transforms((origin, mask))

        origin = torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor(origin) - 0.5

        mask = np.array(mask)
        mask = (torch.tensor(mask) > 128).long()
        return origin, mask

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.origin_mask_list)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-6b5b08e37e6d> in <module>
      3 
      4 plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
----> 5 origin, mask = datasets[phase][idx]
      6 pil_origin = torchvision.transforms.functional.to_pil_image(origin + 0.5).convert("RGB")
      7 pil_mask = torchvision.transforms.functional.to_pil_image(mask.float())

D:\python\care\Lung-segmentation\src\data.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
     16 
     17     def __getitem__(self, idx):
---> 18         origin_name, mask_name = self.origin_mask_list[idx]
     19         origin = Image.open(self.origins_folder / (origin_name + ".png")).convert("P")
     20         mask = Image.open(self.masks_folder / (mask_name + ".png"))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I'm trying to load data but It is showing me the error:
It's Lung Segmentation Project you can go to the repo by GitHub link
and the datasets are in drive if you want more detail then comment to me. I'll provide you

> It's lung segmentation code

For more details take a look at [github](https://github.com/IlliaOvcharenko/lung-segmentation/blob/master/main.ipynb).

Comment: Could you provide the *full* error trace and look at what `datasets[phase][idx]` looks like. It seems you are unpacking an object with more than two elements.

Comment: I am having similar problem. Did you solve this issue?